# How do I export Facebook friends list that includes disabled accounts?

Tags: facebook, export, friends

I just need a list of names, and no other info such as contact details. Other answers to this question, such as [https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/45743/how-do-i-export-or-back-up-my-facebook-friend-list#*=*](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/45743/how-do-i-export-or-back-up-my-facebook-friend-list#_=_), provide poor solutions as the exported lists don't include disabled accounts, which are usually at least a couple of percent of friends (at least in my list).